# How to get the nearest expiration date,

Tags: php, laravel

I have this array string :

```
[
 {"expiration": "0000-00", "quantity": -50},
 {"expiration": "2023-02", "quantity": 100},
 {"expiration": "2022-03", "quantity": 50}
]
```

how to get the nearest expiration date, means here I need to get the third one `2022-03` and ignore others & also ignore the date that comes with `0000-00`

my code:

```
$minDate = "";

foreach (json_decode($row['items']) as $item) {
    if ($item->expiration != "0000-00") {
        $minDate = min($item->expiration);
    }
}

dd($minDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this: -

```
$arr = getNearestExp($row['items']);
print_r($arr);

/**
*To get the Nearest Expiration date
*@input json array of expiration & quantity as 
*per the question
*/
function getNearestExp($items){
    $items = json_decode($items);  // convert the items to json object
    $itemArr = [];

    foreach($items as $item) {
        // exclude the '0000-00' expiration
        if($item->expiration != '0000-00'){ 
            $itemArr[strtotime($item->expiration)] = (array)$item;
        }
        
    }

    // sort the out put array to ASC order to get the smallest value 1st
    ksort($itemArr);

    // Re indexing the array to proper index keys
    $itemArr= array_values($itemArr);

    // return the first value of the array
    return $itemArr[0];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`min()`](https://php.net/min), require two values (or more) and return the lowest value. In your case you gave only one. Then, `min()` cannot compare strings.

You can use several arrays functions such as [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column), [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter), [`sort()`](https://php.net/sort) and [`reset()`](https://php.net/reset) (Less verbose, but could be less efficient with large data) to achieve this :

```php
$data = json_decode('[
 {"expiration": "0000-00", "quantity": -50},
 {"expiration": "2023-02", "quantity": 100},
 {"expiration": "2022-03", "quantity": 50}
]');

// extract 'expiration', remove '0000-00'
$data = array_filter(array_column($data, 'expiration'), fn($item) => $item != '0000-00');
sort($data);
var_dump(reset($data)); // string(7) "2022-03"
```

[demo (3v4l.org)](https://3v4l.org/IRMsf)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.

```
<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

    $json = "[{\"expiration\": \"0000-00\", \"quantity\": -50},{\"expiration\": \"2023-02\", \"quantity\": 100},{\"expiration\": \"2022-03\", \"quantity\": 50}]";
    
    $array = json_decode($json);
    
    $currentDate = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d', date("Y-m-d"));
    $daysDiff = 365;
    $nearest = "";
    
    
    
    for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i ++) {
        
        
        $v = $array[$i];
        
        
        $d = explode("-",$v->expiration);
        
       
        
       
        if(checkdate(intval($d[1]),1,intval($d[0]))) {
        
          
        
            $date =date_create_from_format('Y-m-d',$d[0]."-".$d[1]."-1");
            
            $dateDiff = (array)date_diff($currentDate, $date);
            
            
            
            if($dateDiff["days"] < $daysDiff ) {
                
               $daysDiff = $dateDiff["days"];
                
                $nearest = $v;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    var_dump($nearest)
        
    ?>
```

Bit more low key (it's been a while since I've done php)